# String Replace & Split

Tags: c#, .net, string, rpa, uipath

How to split this values using single Replace & Spit method

```
Tel-0190 Texas 2020-12-31 9 890,00 $ 4,00 $ 8 690,00 $
```

I want to split String Result like this :

```
"Tel-0190" "Texas" "2020-12-31" "9 890,00 $" "4,00 $" "8 690,00 $"
```

I tried:

```
str.Replace(" ","_")
   .Replace("\d* ","\d* ")
   .Replace(" €"," €")
   .Split("_"C)
```

Comment: Tel-0190 Texas 2020-12-31 9 890,00 $ 4,00 $ 8 690,00 $

Comment: I want this splitted like this seperately with String.Replace & Split method

Comment: "Tel-0190" "Texas" "2020-12-31" "9 890,00 $" "4,00 $" "8 690,00 $"

Comment: Use regex......

Comment: The spaces in the numbers and currency symbol are going to make this harder than it could be

Comment: string.Replace only replaces substrings, it doesn't accept regexes (it just treats them as strings)

Comment: And a C-suffix is VB syntax. In C# use `'_'` (single quotes) for characters

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try using Regex:

```
private const string Source = "Tel-0190 Texas 2020-12-31 9 890,00 $ 4,00 $ 8 690,00 $";

private const string RegexPattern =
        @"(?<tel>Tel-\d+) (?<state>Texas) (?<date>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}) (?<num1>[0-9, ]+[$€]) (?<num2>[0-9, ]+[$€]) (?<num3>[0-9, ]+[$€])";
```

I'm using "named groups" in the regex.  I tried to guess your rules.  This code will find the groups:

```
var regex = new Regex(RegexPattern);
var match = regex.Match(Source);
if (match != null && match.Groups.Count == 7)
{
    var groups = match.Groups;
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["tel"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["state"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["date"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["num1"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["num2"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(groups["num3"]);
}
```

The result looks like:

```
Tel-0190
Texas
2020-12-31
9 890,00 $
4,00 $
8 690,00 $
```

Comment: Just a guess but I doubt it should match "Texas" exactly.

Comment: @juharr: that's likely a good guess, but there's no other info to go on in the question